# Fracturing and Necking

Tags: deformation

I am trying to model the deformation of an object after it has surpassed its UTS, before its ultimate failure, what formulas/methods are used to calculate this? My assumption is they have to do with necking/fracturing, although I can only ever seem to find formulas relating to the stress.

Comment: You are mixing UTS with maximum load.   As the test bar necks , the load area decreases.

Comment: Hi, It is because I am modeling in FEA, for which only the data for up to UTS is valid, after that the model would need to change, I assume by including necking and fracturing, but I do not know the formulas.